# Change the number of threads values in JMeter according to the Loop Count value

Tags: jmeter

I would like to change the number of threads values in JMeter according to the Loop Count value.
Number of Threads values are 1 when Loop Count values are 1,
Number of Threads values ​​when Loop Count value is 2,
When the Loop Count value is n, I would like to change the Number of Threads value to n.
How do we do that?

Now JMeter is using 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same (or different) property for threads and loop count, e.g.

On Thread Group settings put in number of threads and loop count get property method

```
 ${__P(count)}
```

And send the property in command line:

```
jmeter -n -Jcount=4 -t your.jmx
```

For count 4 flow will execute 16 times (4 threads * 4 loops)

Comment: Actually, I don't want 16 times result. First loop result is 1 * 1, Second loop result is 2*1, Third loop result is 3*1, Last loop result is n*1

Comment: @JPlay each thread will execute request(s) and each loop will execute request(s) if both set to 4, each request will be 16

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your request is not very clear, given you know the number of loops you can use the same [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) as the number of Threads

Whatever. You can change the number of threads for every Thread Group in your Test Plan to be equal to the number of loops of that Thread Group by:

1. Adding [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
2. Adding [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Putting the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
   def testPlan = engine.test
   def threadGroupSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.class)
   testPlan.traverse(threadGroupSearch)
   threadGroupSearch.getSearchResults().each { threadGroup ->
       def loops = threadGroup.getSamplerController().getPropertyAsInt('LoopController.loops')
       threadGroup.setNumThreads(loops)
   }
   ```